# Can not find or load main class java

Tags: java, windows, maven, cmd, classpath

I have bat file like:

```
java -cp "./lib/*:." TestRunner
```

When I run bat file I have got

```
Can not load main class TestRunner
```

Before I had  command like:

```
java -cp .\lib\*;. TestRunner
```

and

```
java -cp .\lib\*;. com.pkg.TestRunner
```

Same error.

Help me understand. I compiled all sources with maven and all storted in target folder `target/src/java/main/com/pkg/TestRunner.class` and all files not paked in jar just compiled and I want to run files from set of compiled files

Maybe maven somehow not specify main class,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pkg</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>AUTOMATION-01</finalName>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <outputDirectory>target/site</outputDirectory>
    </reporting>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>release-profile</id>

            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

My tree:

```
\---target
    +---classes
    |   +---com
    |   |   +---example
    |   |   |   \---ru
    |   |   |       \---pkg
    |   |   |           \---webservices
    |   |   |               +---submission
    |   |   |               |   \---submissionapi
    |   |   |               \---synchronisation
    |   |   |                   \---syncsfdataapi
    |   |   +---module
    |   |   |   +---ac
    |   |   |   |   \---ws
    |   |   |   |       \---tt
    |   |   |   |           \---webservice
    |   |   |   |               \---pc
    |   |   |   |                   \---quoting
    |   |   |   |                       \---quotingapi
    |   |   |   \---ws
    |   |   |       \---soapheaders
    |   |   \---pkg
    |   |       +---comparation
    |   |       +---filters
    |   |       +---model
    |   |       +---runner
    |   |       +---utils
    |   |       \---ws
    |   \---data_request
    |       +---request
    |       \---responce
    \---maven-status
        \---maven-compiler-plugin
            \---compile
                \---default-compile
```

Comment: what if you remove the `*`? Is the `.class` file inside `lib/com/pkg` ?

Comment: in which folder dou you run java? On which operating system you run?

Comment: I run it in same folder where TestRunner placed target/src/java/main/com/pkg/  I have windows and set java to my classpath. I did not add TestRunner to my classpath

Comment: `target/src/java/main/...` looks as if something is mixed up in your `pom.xml`. There should be a `src\main\com\pkg\...` folder in your project with all your sources. And they get compiled with maven to `target\classes\com\pkg\...`. Can you show us your pom?

Comment: Which package TestRunner belongs to?

Comment: com.pkg.runner.TestRunner.class

Comment: How can I add all classes in subfolders as well to my classpath. All sub directories with class files in it

Comment: You have a lot of redundant settings in your pom. You should clean it first. As far as I can see you can least remove all directory entries. Can you try that and post update? With stripped pom?

Comment: When you have directory with subfolders and classes in it then you just give "top" directory as classpath entry. The subfolders represent package structure of your sources and class files are in these folders. You don't add each package as classpath.

Comment: java -cp "\lib\*;\target\classes\*;." TestRunner I and up with this and still have same error

Comment: I say in my maven pom to save compiled classes to target folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried without `:.` because this look like a [bash syntax](https://superuser.com/questions/965870/what-does-this-strange-symbol-in-bash-mean) that mean if `.\lib\*` doesn't exist then use the current dir `.`

If you are on windows, I suggest remove `:.` and try one of this variation

```
java -cp "./lib/*" TestRunner 
java -cp ".\\lib\\*" TestRunner 
java -cp "lib\*" TestRunner
```

all of this use relative path. If it fail you should try with the fullpath:

```
java -cp "c:/some/folder/lib" TestRunner 
java -cp "c:\\some\\folder\\lib" TestRunner
```

**update:**

Try to transpose this example grabbed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_to_execute_Java_programs)

```
D:\myprogram\
      |
      ---> org\
            |
            ---> mypackage\
                     |
                     ---> HelloWorld.class
                     ---> SupportClass.class
                     ---> UtilClass.class
```

.

```
java -classpath D:\myprogram org.mypackage.HelloWorld
```

Comment: How can I add all classes in subfolders as well to my classpath. All sub directories with class files in it

Comment: java -cp "\lib\*;\target\classes\*;." TestRunner

Comment: I end up with this and still have same probkem java -cp "\lib\*;\target\classes\*;." TestRunner

Comment: Updated by your request

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Add to the maven pom.xml instructions to place info about main class and required libs into MANIFEST.MF:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.pkg.TestRunner</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After perform package you can start application with command

```
java -jar project.jar
```

where project - the name of project.

Comment: OP says he is executing "unpacked" classes. I think he means classes that are not packaged in a jar.

Comment: I don't need jar file. I want set of my .class files

Comment: How can I add all classes in subfolders as well to my classpath. All sub directories with class files in it

Answer (score 0):

Since TestRunner lives in `com.pkg.runner` package, first of all try to run it with:

```
java -classpath . com.pkg.runner.TestRunner
```

Note, when you run `java` command you must be one directore above from `com` folder.

Write here the result

Comment: How can I add all classes in subfolders as well to my classpath. All sub directories with class files in it

Comment: You didn't answer what was the result. I guess you got ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: No sir still same error can not find or load main class